# How to use AADHAR authentication api using OTP request

Tags: authentication, digital-signature, mobile-application, one-time-password, aadhaar

I am in need to use AADHAR API. Basically, we are developing a mobile app for our health care client and in that, we are doing patient registration. Now here we want to do simple AADHAR authentication using OTP request wherein the patient will enter his/her AADHAR number and in return gets an OTP which is submitted to AADHAR Auth API and once authentication is successful we will fetch eKYC details of a patient and use them in my app.

Research has done so far:
I have gone through

AADHAR OTP Request API - https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/aadhaar_otp_request_api_2_5.pdf

AADHAR Auth API -
https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/aadhaar_authentication_api_2_5.pdf

Basically I was trying to call both OTP Request and Auth API using postman but that did not work.
While exploring an API it is mentioned that we need to pass `<Signature>Digital signature of AUA</Signature>` as a part of the request body, both in Auth and OTP request API as given in above links. Then we contacted https://www.emudhradigital.com/ and obtained a test certificate in .pfx file format.

Now I am stuck on how do I use this test certificate to call those APIs. Also, there is no clear documentation given on UIDAI website or anywhere like how to use and integrate them. I used postman while doing research but that does not work.

Any hints or help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mahendra

Comment: I m trying to implement the same in my system, please post an update if you have any

Comment: Hey did you find the way.Please share it here it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly mentioned in the document that you should call the API with an AUA/ASA id. So you cannot use that API without AUA/ASA ID.

Answer (score 0):

This Git Repo should help you https://github.com/pingali/pyAadhaarAuth

And You will find Test Data and Certificate and License Key on Aadhaar's Developer Section https://www.uidai.gov.in/ecosystem/authentication-devices-documents/developer-section/916-developer-section/data-and-downloads-section.html

Basically You have To Create XML file's for your Request according to the specified API Spec. All about Encryption and Signatures is mentioned in the spec and the above repo should also help